# Can Python Selenium webdriver use websockets?

Tags: python, selenium, websocket

I'm interested in using python webdriver with websockets in order to control firefox , first locally and later remotely. I'm not finding a lot of documentation or examples on google although there is some evidence that its possible (eg http://blog.imanel.org/moving-forward-with-websockets)

Normally I work locally with webdriver, connecting with something like:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox (executable_path="PATHTOFIREFOX", desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

Is this possible, and if so how would the connection to the driver be made?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: No, I did not .

Comment: On first glance, [this article](https://medium.com/@lagenar/using-headless-chrome-via-the-websockets-interface-5f498fb67e0f) seems to explain how to work with websockets using headless Chrome. I hope that answers your question.