# Selenium standalone websockets and perl

Tags: java, perl, selenium

I have a selenium test configured for a while and has been working as designed.  Recently the app changed to websockets.  Now the test fails consistently because it cannot make the websocket connection.  I went to www.websocket.org/echo.html and the websocket connect fails there even though it says firefox version works with websocket.  When not using the selenium proxy websocket connections works. I've searched and looked all over the place but cannot find out whether selenium standalone will work with websockets.  Is there a proxy setting somewhere or maybe I need to change something in the perl code?

centos 5.11
java 1.8.0.11
selenium standalone 2.48.2
perl 5.8.8
selenium perl module 1.36

Comment: What do you mean by *the Selenium proxy*?

Comment: selenium web driver standalone is a proxy connection for web testing.  When the server is started it loads a profile with the proxy set.  The browser uses the proxy to capture information sent between the browser and web server.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188069/can-python-selenium-webdriver-use-websockets (which doesn't have an answer either).